# Get value from Input text field in angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript, mean-stack

it seems to be an easy question, but nothing what i found worked for me. I have a standard input field in my component.html:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Serial</label>
    <input type="text" name="serial" id="serial" [ngModel]="serial" [value]="serial" class="form-control">
</div>
```

So when the user now submitts the form, how do i get the value he typed into the field? If i do a simple `console.log(this.serial)` in my `onSubmit()` function, i get nothing. I declared `serial: String;` in my component.ts

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You have wrong bound.
You need *banana-in-box* binding `[(ngModel)]="serial"` instead of `[ngModel]="serial"`

`()` in the binding will update `serial` model everytime when the input will be changes. From `input` into `model`

Single `[]` will just bind the data of `serial` if it will be changed by code manually. This will cause to *one-way* binding - from `model` into `input`.

As you guess - together `[()]` they will make *two-way* binding.

Comment: You are welcome. But try to understand what is going. This is one of the core concepts in Angular

Comment: How did you retrieve the value from type script ?

Comment: @Illep In typescript class you already have a property with name `serial` which is the bound one. So you need just to access this property and get the latest value

Answer (score 8):

this is one way binding.
from view to controller.

file code.component.html

```
<label >Code</label>
<input (input)="tcode=$event.target.value" type="text" class="form-control">
<button class="btn btn-success" (click)="submit()">Submit</button>
```

file code.component.ts

```
tcode : string;
submit() {
    console.log("the code :" + this.tcode);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this simple example. Much appreciated.